# I can't stop loading progress in AwesomeButton React

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts

I want to stop this progress and i added a loading state in my code but when i clicked the button and the transaction will be successful, loading progress doesn't stop.

Awesome button demo webpage: https://caferati.me/demo/react-awesome-button

```
onSubmitAdd = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    try {
      const { accounts, contract, addAmount, web3 } = this.state;
      await contract.methods.addMoney().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei(addAmount, "ether"),
      });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
    }
    this.setState({ loading: false, addAmount: "" });
  };
```

Here is my render code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmitAdd}>
                  <div class="spaceTop"></div>
                  <div>
                    <input
                      placeholder="Value of ETH"
                      type="number"
                      id="id1"
                      value={this.state.addAmount}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        this.setState({ addAmount: event.target.value })
                      }
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "#6d6d6d",
                        color: "#fcfcfc",
                        borderRadius: "100px",
                        height: "60px",
                        width: "300px",
                        paddingLeft: "2em",
                        marginBottom: "10px",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <AwesomeButtonProgress
                    action={this.state.loading}
                    type="primary"
                  >
                    Add Money
                  </AwesomeButtonProgress>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per AwesomeButtonProgress docs, to stop the progress, you need to call next() within the action callback function after some asynchronous processing.

```js
<AwesomeButtonProgress
        action={(element, next) => {
            console.log('clicked');
            setTimeout(() => {
                next();
            }, 600);
        }}
        type="primary"
    >
        Add Money
    </AwesomeButtonProgress>;
```

Based on the snippet shared by you, you are just passing `true`/`false` into `action`

You can also refer to this [working example they have as part of the docs](https://caferati.me/demo/react-awesome-button/storybook/?knob-size=large&knob-type=primary&knob-text=Progress&selectedKind=AwesomeButtonProgress&selectedStory=Success&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel)

Comment: When i add this on my code i got " 'action' is not defined  no-undef" error

Comment: @aliercanozgokce I've update the snippet. Sorry I meant to log there to show the click event